# Wake Lock exception

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services

I upgraded my app to use Google Services 7.0. After that I start seeing hundreds of reports of the same exception, as shown in the below stack trace. Mainly from Android 2.3 devices. Prior the upgrade I haven't received any report of such exception. And didn't change anything related to Wake Lock, which I use for a service. Prior to the change I was using Google Analytics v3. Now I am using v4 that comes with Google Services.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: WakeLock under-locked Analytics WakeLock
    at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.release(PowerManager.java:307)
    at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.release(PowerManager.java:282)
    at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock$1.run(PowerManager.java:202)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any idea of what might be going on?

Addendum: I added the following, as described in the documentation of Google Analytics:

```
   <!-- Enable background dispatching to improve delivery on non-Google Play devices -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"/>
```

Now, I removed it and it seems that the exception vanished. I would like to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The only valid reason that I could find to your question is because, **`**Analytics needs network to send your hits. The optional wake lock permission help with reliable dispatching**`** .

Just to ensure that Google is able to track the crash in GCM in devices running 2.3 and older, they force you to add the Analytics permission.

Comment: My app already uses that permission for notifications. As I said, as soon I removed the receiver the problem vanished.